# By its acronym / in its acronym?

Tags: expressions, acronyms

CONTEXT: Expressing that some given acronym corresponds to a language different from the one used to give the full name of a certain entity.

QUESTION: Is the following sentence (in **bold**) correct and natural in English?

> [...] The Spanish Society for Acronyms (SEA, **in its Spanish acronym**) [...]

If not, should **"by its Spanish acronym"** should be rather used, instead?

Comment: Prefer **by**. Alternatively, **known in Spain by the acronym SEA**.

Comment: Whether you would use either really depends on whether the document you're creating will be governed by a house style sheet or a particular style guide. Some guides call for presenting the foreign name and acronym and then the English translation of the name in  square brackets afterwards, totally eliminating the need to choose between those two prepositions.  Things can get complicated when the organization is already known to English speakers by a different acronym that reflects English word order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe better choices are:

> SEA, by its Spanish acronym
>
> SEA, its acronym in Spanish